# Averaging over N files

Tags: python, numpy, io

I have N files, each of them looks like:

```
   #p     q     s      val1     val2
   0.5    0.2   0.3     1.2      0.8
   0.1    0.9   0.1     1.8      0.8
   0.2    0.3   0.2     0.5      0.3
   ...    ...   ...     ...      ...
```

and I need to average each corresponding value in the files in order to create a "MeanFile.txt" that will contain the mean of the elements  over the files.

In my programs I usually do this:

```
    import pylab
    import glob
    import numpy
    list_of_files=glob.glob('*.txt')
    N = number_of_files
    R = number_of_rows_in_each_file

    p = numpy.zeros(N,R)
    q = numpy.zeros(N,R)
    s = numpy.zeros(N,R)
    val1 = numpy.zeros(N,R)
    val2 = numpy.zeros(N,R)
    for (i,filename) in zip(range(0,N),list_of_files):
            p[i],q[i],s[i],val1[i],val2[i] = pylab.loadtxt(filename, unpack = True)
```

and then

```
    out_file = open("Results.dat","w")
    out_file.write("#\n")   
    for j in range(0,R):
          out_file.write("%.3f  %.3f  %.3f  %.3f  %.3f  %.3f  %.3f  %.3f \n" %(p.mean(0)[j],q.mean(0)[j],s.mean(0)[j], val1.mean(0)[j],val2.mean(0)[j]))
```

I am sure that there must be an easier way, because if I get a new set of data that has a different number of variables, for example:

```
   #p     q     s  val1     val2    theta
   0.5    0.2   0.3     1.2      0.8     1
   0.1    0.9   0.1     1.8      0.8     1
   0.2    0.3   0.2     0.5      0.3     2
   ...    ...   ...     ...      ...     ...
```

I would need to introduce new variables as well and repeat the steps. Is there a simpler way of averaging over N files? for example, using  numpy.loadtxt to take al the data in a unique list? My data are separated by 4 spacec by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.loadtxt` will auto separate by whitespace so this should work

```
import glob
import numpy as np

for count, file in enumerate(glob.glob('*.txt'), 1):
    if count == 1:
        summed = np.loadtxt(file)
    else:
        summed += np.loadtxt(file)

mean = summed / count

np.savetxt('out.txt', mean, fmt='%.3f', delimiter='   ')
```

Output file example

```
0.500   0.200   0.300   1.200   0.800   1.000
0.100   0.900   0.100   1.800   0.800   1.000
0.200   0.300   0.200   0.500   0.300   2.000
```